# Android unpinning screen - how to require always two keys even if some accessibility service is enabled

Tags: android, accessibility, android-screen-pinning

I'm making a simple app for kids and I want to use screen pinning method built in Android API which is startLockTask(). The problem is when any of accessibility service is enabled it's enough to touch and hold just one key to unpin the screen. It's too easy to unlock an app. It would be perfect if it always require 2 keys pressed simultaneously (like it does if no accessibility service is enabled). 
Is there any way that screen pinning will ignore accessibility mode?

Device owner app is not the solution I'm looking for. I know I could use accessibility and other hacks to get buttons disabled but as I heard Google will be inspecting Google Play apps and remove those which use accessibility services inappropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to launch your app as a default launcher app which contains only your application logic.